# Record Video using surface view android

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder, video-recording

I have to create an android app in which i am trying to record video and capture image using surface view.
Up to now i am able to capture video but facing problem in record video.
 My code for video recording is -

```
onCreate(){
      ..
     surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
     surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
     surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
     startRecording();
     .
     .
}


protected void startRecording() throws IOException
    {
        if(mCamera==null)
            mCamera = Camera.open();

         String filename;
         String path;

         path= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString();

         Date date=new Date();
         filename="/rec"+date.toString().replace(" ", "_").replace(":", "_")+".mp4";

         File file=new File(path,filename);

        mrec = new MediaRecorder(); 

        mCamera.lock();
        mCamera.unlock();


        mrec.setCamera(mCamera);    
        mrec.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mrec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);     
        mrec.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mrec.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
        mrec.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mrec.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
        mrec.setOutputFile(path+filename);
        mrec.setMaxDuration(10000); 
  }
       @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,int                height) {      

        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();      
        parameters.setPreviewSize(width, height);     
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);       
        mCamera.startPreview(); 

    }
```

but app force close when onSurfaceChange method code is called at line -
mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder); with exception java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed

so how can i manage it so i can start video recording.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is failing because not all devices support arbitrary preview sizes. Apparently some do but you can't rely on it.

Comment: so how can i handle this problem.

Comment: Check my answer below and it has to be done inside `surfaceChanged` method.

Comment: Check this link https://github.com/krazykira/CuXtomCam/blob/master/CuXtom%20Cam%20Library/src/com/glass/cuxtomcam/CuxtomCamActivity.java#L372

Comment: The complete example which I posted didn't help you?

Comment: no that was also giving exception while start media recorder.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check this code, hopefully it works..

```
import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MediaRecorderRecipe extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private final String VIDEO_PATH_NAME = "/mnt/sdcard/VGA_30fps_512vbrate.mp4";

private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
private Camera mCamera;
private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private View mToggleButton;
private boolean mInitSuccesful;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.media_recorder_recipe);

    // we shall take the video in landscape orientation
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
    mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    mToggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleRecordingButton);
    mToggleButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        // toggle video recording
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (((ToggleButton)v).isChecked()) {
                mMediaRecorder.start();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10 * 1000); // This will recode for 10 seconds, if you don't want then just remove it.
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finish();
            }
            else {
                mMediaRecorder.stop();
                mMediaRecorder.reset();
                try {
                    initRecorder(mHolder.getSurface());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });     
}

/* Init the MediaRecorder, the order the methods are called is vital to
 * its correct functioning */
private void initRecorder(Surface surface) throws IOException {
    // It is very important to unlock the camera before doing setCamera
    // or it will results in a black preview
    if(mCamera == null) {
        mCamera = Camera.open();
        mCamera.unlock();
    }

    if(mMediaRecorder == null)  mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surface);
    mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
   //       mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(8);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(512 * 1000);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(640, 480);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(VIDEO_PATH_NAME);

    try {
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // This is thrown if the previous calls are not called with the 
        // proper order
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mInitSuccesful = true;
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        if(!mInitSuccesful)
            initRecorder(mHolder.getSurface());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    shutdown();
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {}

private void shutdown() {
    // Release MediaRecorder and especially the Camera as it's a shared
    // object that can be used by other applications
    mMediaRecorder.reset();
    mMediaRecorder.release();
    mCamera.release();

    // once the objects have been released they can't be reused
    mMediaRecorder = null;
    mCamera = null;
}
```

Permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

XML FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ToggleButton
 android:id="@+id/toggleRecordingButton"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:textOff="Start Recording" 
 android:textOn="Stop Recording"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
<FrameLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/surfaceView" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"></SurfaceView>

</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Create a File for saving an image or video**

```
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
              Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
    // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
    // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
        "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
        "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}
```

Comment: if I want to increase time of recording ?

Comment: I am able to record video using your code..now is it possible to capture image simultaneously when recording is going on?

Comment: hii..  @Aniruddha i'm able to record video but my app is automatically destroy once recording is completed after 10sec.. can you tell me the reason behind this? thank you in advance

Comment: @RuchaBhatt: Inside mToggleButton.setOnClickListener method, there is finish() after catch block, please comment finish(), then your app will not close.

Comment: i'll just copy and past your code but it's give me a error `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.SurfaceHolder android.view.SurfaceView.getHolder()' on a null object reference`

Comment: @Aniruddha is it possible to use the media recorder to record the surface which I am using in virtual display of media projection for screen recording?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of available preview sizes by calling getSupportedPreviewSizes in the Camera.Parameters object returned by Camera.getParameters. [Check here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPreviewSizes%28%29)

Add these below code inside `surfaceChanged` method

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();  
   List<Camera.Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();  
   Camera.Size cs = sizes.get(0);  // You need to choose the most appropriate previewSize for your app. So select one from the list
   parameters.setPreviewSize(cs.width, cs.height);  
   camera.setParameters(parameters);
   camera.startPreview();
```

**EDIT** Change your `surfaceChanged` method like below and check

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.
        Log.d("Function", "surfaceChanged");
        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
          // preview surface does not exist
          return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
          // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here


        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();  returns null on my samsung s7562

Comment: replace `getSupportedPreviewSizes` with `getPreviewSize` and check.

Comment: List<Camera.Size> sizes = (List<Size>) parameters.getPreviewSize(); also returns null

Comment: Can you just check with different cellphone?

Comment: The doc says `This method will always return a list with at least one element.` Please change your cellphone and check once.

Comment: i have tried in another device samsung ss7392 and it gives exception in geting parameters -java.lang.RuntimeException: getParameters failed (empty parameters)

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941625/correct-handling-of-exception-getparameters-failed-empty-parameters

Comment: yes you are right i have comment camera.unlock() and it gives list of parameters but gives exception on startPreview failed.I have unlocked camera before call  mCamera.startPreview();

Comment: Change your `surfaceChanged` method like this and try. Remove these lines `Parameters parameters= mCamera.getParameters();
    parameters.setPreviewSize(w, h);
    camera.setParameters(parameters);` and check my edited answer.

Comment: yeah its working without any exception but video is not created or stored in sdcard.

Comment: If my answer solved your initial question then please up vote it and accept. For video is not created or stored in sdcard, create a new thread of question.

Comment: now i am able to store video file but that file is of 0kb,means nothing is recorded in it.So can you please help what the problem in it.

Comment: Seems like you accepted my answer and again deselected it. Appreciate when someone helps you, show some gratitude. Anyways happy coding.

Comment: but your code is not working completely,video file is created but nothing is recorded as my initial question how can i record video using surface view.

Comment: when i call recorder.start() after recorder.prepare() it force close giving exception that fail to start media  recoder.

Comment: Are you trying this code on API level less than 13? I will suggest you 2 things, try them and let me know. 1] Before `camera.unlock()`, call `camera.lock()` and then `camera.unlock()`. 2] Try removing `mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30)` line. Check them separately. Seems like first one will help you.