# Using VideoCaptureConfig, I want to record a video without audio. Is it possible?. I tried to mute mic but it's not working

Tags: android, android-camerax

I'm trying to record video using CameraX and VideoCaptureConfig with the following code.

```
videoCapture = VideoCaptureConfig.Builder().apply {
              setTargetRotation(rotation)
              setVideoFrameRate(5)
              setTargetResolution(Size(320, 480))

          }.build()
```

I want to record a video without audio. How can I do this?

I tried to mute mic suggested with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41103030/android-mute-microphone-while-recording-video). But It's not working.