# getParameters failed affectiva

Tags: android, affdex-sdk

In few devices I am getiing below exceptions after integrating affdex sdk.Could you please let me know if we need to make any changes to fix it?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: getParameters failed (empty parameters)
                                                                       at android.hardware.Camera.native_getParameters(Native Method)
                                                                       at android.hardware.Camera.getParameters(Camera.java:1896)
                                                                       at com.affectiva.android.affdex.sdk.detector.CameraHelper.e(SourceFile:291)
                                                                       at com.affectiva.android.affdex.sdk.detector.CameraHelper.e(SourceFile:36)
                                                                       at com.affectiva.android.affdex.sdk.detector.CameraHelper$1.onPreviewFrame(SourceFile:143)
                                                                       at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:1110)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: after a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941625/correct-handling-of-exception-getparameters-failed-empty-parameters, it looks like there might be a race condition.  On which Android version(s) are you seeing the problem?

Comment: Device Details  Device Name:Lenovo Vibe
Android Version:6.0
Model Number: A7020a48